# Meaning of \old in ACSL post-conditions

Tags: design-by-contract, formal-verification, frama-c

I am a newbie user of Frama-C and have a few questions regarding  assertions 
over pointers.

Consider the C fragment below involving:

- two related data structures Data and Handle, s.t. Handle has a pointer to Data;
- a  'state' field in Data indicating whether some hypothetical operation has completed
- three  functions: init(), start_operation() and wait();
- a main() function using the above, and containing 6 assertions (A1-A6)

Now, why is it that A5 and A6 cannot be asserted with the WP verifier ("frama-c -wp file.c")
Shouldn't they hold due to the last "ensures" clause on start_operation()?

What am I doing wrong?

Best,

Eduardo

```
typedef enum 
{ 
  PENDING, NOT_PENDING
} DataState;

typedef struct 
{
  DataState state;
  int value;  
} Data;


typedef struct 
{
  Data* data;
  int id;
} Handle;

/*@
  @ ensures \valid(\result);
  @ ensures \result->state == NOT_PENDING;
  @*/
Data* init(void);

/*@ 
  @ requires data->state == NOT_PENDING;
  @ ensures data->state == PENDING;
  @ ensures \result->data == data;
  @*/  
 Handle* start_operation(Data* data, int to);

/*@
  @ requires handle->data->state == PENDING;
  @ ensures handle->data->state == NOT_PENDING;
  @ ensures handle->data == \old(handle)->data;
  @*/  
 void wait(Handle* handle);


 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
  Data* data = init();
  /*@ assert A1: data->state == NOT_PENDING; */

  Handle* h = start_operation(data,0);
  /*@ assert A2: data->state == PENDING; */
  /*@ assert A3: h->data == data; */

  wait(h);
  /*@ assert A4: h->data->state == NOT_PENDING; */
  /*@ assert A5: data->state == NOT_PENDING; */
  /*@ assert A6: h->data == data; */

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I have added tags formal-verification and design-by-contract to the question. If followers of these tags mind seeing this kind of question, please blame me, not the OP. I did not add the C tag because I expect most C programmers would not care about them. I may be wrong—obviously a lot of people do not care whether their C-tagged questions are interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are verifying some tricky memory manipulations for a “newbie”.

The ACSL construct `\old` does not work exactly like you think it does.

First, `\old(handle)` in a post-condition is the same as `handle`, because `handle` is a parameter. A contract is intended to be used from the point of view of callers. Even if the function `wait` modified `handle` (which would be unusual but is possible), its contract would still be intended to relate values passed as argument by the caller and the state returned by the function to the caller.

In short, **in an ACSL post-condition, `parameter` always means `\old(parameter)`** (even if the function modifies `parameter` like a local variable).

Second, the rule above is only for parameters. For global variables and memory accesses, the post-condition is considered to apply to the post-state, as you would expect from its name. The construct `\old(handle)->data` that you wrote, and that is equivalent to `handle->data`, means “the field `.data` that the old value of handle points to in the new state”, so that the post-condition `handle->data == \old(handle)->data` is a tautology and probably not what you intended.

From the context, it appears that you intended `handle->data == \old(handle->data)` instead, which means "the field `.data` that the old value of `handle` points to in the new state is equal to the field `.data` that the old value of `handle` points to in the old state”. With that change, all the assertions in your program get proved for me (using Alt-Ergo 0.93).

Comment: Yes, you understood my intent. Using "handle->data == \old(handle->data)" it works. Thanks a lot.